# How do we pass data into an @Input() of a dynamically generated component in Angular 13?

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a component that has a pretty broad and abstract range of use on a website I'm building.  In each instance I pass a component to it through an `@Input()` and it uses `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` to resolve it then it gets embedded into an `<iframe>`.

Due to having so many use cases I have to take into consideration that this component will never know what it's going to receive to have to embed.  Some of these components will be using broadcast channels and I want to pass the name of the channel into an `@Input()` on the component.

The way I have it set up looks like this

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterContentChecked {

    //    The component I'll be embedding into the iframe.
    @Input() ExampleComponent! : Type<Component>;

    //    For the broadcastChannel name if one is to be used
    @Input() DataChannelName : string = '';

    //    The iframe I'll be embedding the component into
    @ViewChild('responsiveWindow', {static: true}) ResponsiveWindow!: ElementRef;



    constructor(
        private vcRef : ViewContainerRef,
        private cdr   : ChangeDetectorRef,
        //    other stuff
    ){}



    ngOnInit(): void {
    
        this.generateComponent();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {

        //  stuff that's irrelevant to the question
    }

    ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }



    private generateComponent(): void {

        //    References the iframe
        const frame = this.ResponsiveWindow?.nativeElement.contentDocument ||
                      this.ResponsiveWindow?.nativeElement.contentWindow;

        //    Resolves the ExampleComponent
        const componentInstance : ComponentRef<unknown> = this.vcRef.createComponent(this.ExampleComponent);


        //    Checks if both the DataChannel property is set and if the component has
        //    a ChannelName input and if so pass the value into the input
        if(
             this.DataChannelName !== '' &&
             (<ComponentRef<unknown>>componentInstance.instance).hasOwnProperty('ChannelName')
          ){
               
               console.log('this component has an input');

               //    This doesn't work but just showing what I would
               //    like to do somehow.
               componentInstance.instance.ChannelName = this.DataChannelName;
        }

        //    Embeds component into iframe
        frame.body.appendChild(componentInstance.location.nativeElement);

    }

}
```

Now when I look at the documentation for [ComponentRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef) I see that all the properties are `Read-Only`which means I can't write to them.  When I `console.log()` the `componentInstance` I see that the `ChannelName` property does exist in the `instance` object of the component which I'm guessing that's where I'll need to access it.

I came across a few tutorials that showed doing it the way I attempted to above but those are from 2020 and prior.  Angular 13 came out while I've been working on this so I was directly in tune with the fact they changed things regarding the `ComponentFactoryResolver` and am guessing this method for passing values to an `@Input()` has changed with it however I can't seem to find anything in the docs or on the web showing an updated way of doing this.  Does anyone know how we should do this?

***UPDATE***

I made [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kncrsb?file=src/app/responsive-frame/responsive-frame.component.ts) to add here for everyone to poke around at and I figured out a solution which is to use type indexing like this

```
componentInstance.instance['DataChannel'] = this.DataChannelName;
```

If you open the view in a separate window and inspect it you'll see the embedded component `console.log()`s the channel name passed into it from the code above.  However it doesn't work on my own computer. I get an `Object is of type unknown` error.

Comment: What you have should work fine, however, ChannelName => DataChannelName?

Comment: `componentInstance.ref.channel="what-ever"`?

Comment: @Eliseo there is no `ref` object on the `componentInstance`.

Comment: @MikeOne it fails to compile because `Object is of type unknown`.  As far as the property names, the input is indeed named `ChannelName` inside the components I'm embedding while in the component in question I use `DataChannelName`.

Comment: @Optiq, sorry it was `instance`

Comment: @Eliseo oh..... well... that's kinda what I originally tried which is in the code above that didn't work, lol.